# What is the Fourier Transform of a brownian motion?

Tags: time-series, signal-processing, fourier-transform, random-walk, noise

I looked into this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_noise and it says that:

If we have a brownian motion $W(t) = \int _{0}^{t} dW(s)$, then given that the spectral density of white noise is constant 
 $S_0 = \left|\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{dW(t)}{dt}\right](\omega)\right|^2 = \text{const}$

Note that here $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform and $S_0$ is a constant. An important property of this transform is that the derivative of any distribution transforms as

$\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{dW(t)}{dt}\right](\omega) = i \omega \mathcal{F}[W(t)](\omega) $

from which we can conclude that the power spectrum of Brownian noise is

$S(\omega)= \left|\mathcal{F}[W(t)](\omega)\right|^2= \frac{S_0}{\omega^2}$

I don't understand this demonstration. Do you have a more detailed explanation or a link to a more detailed proof?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the demonstration amounts to dividing both sides of the penultimate equation by $|i\omega|^2$. Perhaps you could be a little clearer, then, about what part you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand the first equation: the FT of the derivative of W is iw times the FT of W.

Comment: It's just integration by parts: see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html starting at equation (34).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned above, the first equation about which you were confused is a property of the Fourier transform. Here is a very explicit derivation. First define the Fourier transform over a finite interval $(a,b)$ as 
$$
\mathcal{F}\left\{f(t)\right\} = \int_{(a,b)} f(t) e^{-i \omega t}\ dt.
$$
With suitable technical considerations (if you care: that $f(t)$ is in the Sobolev space $W^{1,1}(a,b)$, which means that both $f$ and its derivative $f'$ are absolutely integrable over $(a,b)$) we can use our usual integration by parts formula: $\int u\ dv = uv|_{a}^b - \int v\ du$, where we will 
set $u = e^{-i \omega t}$ and $dv = f'(t) dt$. 
Then we have 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int e^{i \omega t}\frac{d}{dt} f(t)\ dt &= -i \omega e^{-i\omega t}f(t)\Big|_a^b - \int -i\omega e^{-i \omega t}f(t)\ dt \\
&= -i \omega \left(e^{-i \omega b}f(b) - e^{-i\omega a} f(a) \right) 
+ i\omega \int f(t) e^{-i\omega t}\ dt\\
&= -i \omega \left(e^{-i \omega b}f(b) - e^{-i\omega a} f(a) \right) + i \omega \mathcal{F}\left\{ f(t) \right\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

If your function $f$ is well-behaved enough (if you somehow define a sequence of functions $f_n$ that converge to a limiting function and agree with $f$ on $(a,b)$, and if you can find a function $g$ so that, for any sequence of intervals $I_n$ converging to $\mathbb{R}$ you have $|f_n| \leq g$ for all $n$) then the constant term above cancels and you have the desired result.

All the formality seems a little contrived, and indeed from the point of view of a physicist it is a little bit---we just do this and don't worry about the formality. But if you want to get into the details, they are important. Suppose you were trying to do this with a random function: the Wiener process $\mathcal{W}(t)$, for example. All right, since $\mathcal{W}(t)$ is a.s. continuous everywhere then we can a.s. Riemann-Stieltjes integrate it as above. But its "derivative" is not well-defined in the traditional sense since $\mathcal{W}(t)$ is a.s. differentiable nowhere! Oops.

Everything does end up working out, and so even though the derivation you gave above is, technically-speaking, wrong, since $\frac{d}{dt}\mathcal{W}(t)$ is not defined, it is morally correct and, in physics, we use it all the time.

Comment: I will post an answer later on how this can be discussed more rigorously. I would like to point out, however, that your derivation of the Fourier differentiation rule is not very general, while the rule itself is very general: It holds for any tempered distribution. In particular, it holds for Dirac‘s delta or for plane waves, and many other functions/distributions (including Brownian paths) which are very far from being differentiable or Sobolev functions. (Sobolev functions are essentially functions whose distributional derivatives are again functions, so this will not be the case then)

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, I know this thread is old, but I feel like some statements are not very clear and/or misleading, and also I would like to add a more mathematically sound perspective on the matter.

As was already pointed out, a Brownian path is with probability 1 not differentiable anywhere, at least not in a usual sense. It is correct that $dW/dt$ is defined in a distributional sense, and as such its Fourier transform can be taken. But the result is a priori a distribution. The actual problem is the premise that "the spectral density of white noise is a constant". At that point, you're miles away from any rigorous definition. Moreover, although you can find this claim a lot, it't not correct, or at least it's misleading.

First of all, we should restrict ourselves to a Fourier decomposition on a finite interval, i.e. with discrete frequencies (because this is the only setting in which we can make meaningful statements). Let's say we're on $[0, 1]$. Then it's true that white noise has a flat spectral density in the sense that
$$ E \left[ \left\vert \int_0^1 e^{-i \omega t} dW_t \right\vert ^2\right] = 1 , $$
which is independent of $\omega$. It is not true, however, that $\left\vert \int_0^1 e^{-i \omega t} dW_t \right\vert ^2$ is a constant. Rather, it follows a $\chi^2$ distribution.

However, $\int \phi(t) dW_t$ is a stochastic integral, it cannot be understood as $\int \phi(t) \frac{dW_t}{dt}dt$. Now, stochastic calculus tells us that, for any deterministic function $\phi(t)$, $\int_0^1 \phi(t)\,dW_t$ is a random variable with normal distribution with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2 = \int_0^t \vert \phi(t) \vert^2\, dt$.

How does this help? Well, we can write the Fourier transform as
$$ \int_0^1 e^{-i \omega t} W_t dt = \int_0^1 e^{-i \omega t} \left( \int_0^s dW_s \right) dt = \int_0^1 \left( \int_s^1 e^{- i \omega t} d t \right) dW_s = \int_0^1 \phi(s)\, dW_s ,$$
with $$\phi(s) = \frac{i}{ \omega} (1 - e^{- i \omega s}).$$
And this function has
$$\int_0^1 \vert \phi (s) \vert^2\, ds = 2 / \omega^2 .$$

This means that the $\omega$-th Fourier coefficient, $\omega \in 2 \pi \mathbb Z$,  has distribution $\mathcal N (0, 2 / \omega^2 )$.

In fact, you can simulate a Brownian path by sampling independent standard normal variables $Z_n \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$, for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$, and puting
$$ W(t) := Z_0 t + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt 2 Z_n}{\pi n} \sin (\pi n t). $$
But if you fix the absolute value of $Z_n$ and just choose the sign randomly, you will end up with something else.

If you really want to know what white noise is: It can be rigorously defined as a random tempered distribution (i.e. an extremely singular object!) following a certain law. Like a finite-dimensional random variable, this law can be defined via a characteristic function (existence is guaranteed by the Bochner-Minlos-Sazanov theorem). In infinite dimensions, this looks like this: The white noise distribution $T$ is distributed such, that for every Schwartz function (every smooth function that decays faster than any inverse polynomial) $\phi (t)$,
$$ E [ e^{i (T, \phi )} ] = e^{- \frac 1 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \vert \phi(t) \vert^2 d t }$$
The field of mathematics that deals with this is called White Noise Analysis.